# How do I store value from createApi to redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to store a value of a user, data(name, email and other), that was fetched using `createApi` to Redux store. I don't know how to do it or what is the good practice here.

userApi.js

```js
export const userApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "userApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000" ,
    credentials: "include",
    tagTypes: ['Users'],
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const { accessToken } = getState().auth;
      if (accessToken) {
        headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
      }
      return headers;
    }
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: () => "/users",
      // this is used when when we want to validate and update UI
      providesTags: ["Users"],
      //this is used to specify which object we wanna show
      transformResponse: (response) => response.data,
    }),
    loginUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (value) => ({
        url: "/login",
        method: "POST",
        body: value,
      })
    }),
...

export const { 
  useGetUsersQuery, 
  useLoginUserMutation
} = userApi;
```

I'm trying put the value in to the state of this slice.

authSlice.js

```js
const initialState = {
  user: null,
  accessToken : null,
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    setAccessToken: (state, action) => {
      state.accessToken = action.payload;
    },
    logOut: () => initialState
  },
})

export const { setUser, setAccessToken, logOut } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer

export const selectUser = (state) => state.auth.user;
export const selectAccessToken = (state) => state.auth.accessToken;
```

I watch a tutorial before and I remember that you can use `extraReducer` and `addCase` but I don't remember the video name and I don't know if that is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
import { setUser, setAccessToken } from '[API/PATH]';
```

then you have access dispatch in `onCacheEntryAdded`.
you can do it with `queryFn` too you have the dispatch as the second argument like `queryFn: (value, { dispatch }) => ...`

```
 loginUser : builder.mutation({
      query: (value) => ({
        url : "/login",
        method : "POST",
        body : value,
      })
    }),
    async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { cacheDataLoaded, dispatch, getCacheEntry }) {
                await cacheDataLoaded;
                const result = getCacheEntry();
                const { data } = result;
                const { accessToken } = data;
                dispatch(setUser(data));
                dispatch(setAccessToken(accessToken))
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options available for saving query/mutation responses over into your existing Redux state.

**Method 1:** Use the endpoint's [`onQueryStarted`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted) to dispatch actions to the store.

```js
import { setUser } from '../path/to/authSlice';

...

loginUser: builder.mutation({
  query: (body) => ({
    url: "/login",
    method: "POST",
    body,
  }),
  onQueryStarted: async (body, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
      // Success, set the user in state
      dispatch(setUser(data));
    } catch(error) {
      // Failure, reset the user back to null
      dispatch(setUser(null));
    }
  },
}),
```

**Method 2:** Use an endpoint [matcher](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#matchers) in a state slice to match a fulfilled/rejected query/mutation.

```js
import { userApi } from '.../path/to/userApi';

...

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    setAccessToken: (state, action) => {
      state.accessToken = action.payload;
    },
    logOut: () => initialState
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addMatcher(
        userApi.endpoints.loginUser.matchFulfilled,
        (state, action) => {
          state.user = action.payload; // or maybe action.payload.data, I don't know what your response looks like
        }
      )
      .addMatcher(
        userApi.endpoints.loginUser.matchRejected,
        (state, action) => {
          state.user = null;
        }
      );
  },
});
```